# RepoDB - Ignore property

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm

I'm using RepoDB to connect with SQL Server Database and I want to ignore specific properties of my object but I didn't find how to do that.

[RepoDB docs](https://repodb.net/)

Here an example of what exaclty I want.
***It's not a real scenario...**

```cs
public class Person{

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string ZipCode { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }

  //[Ignore this property]
  public List<Dependant> Dependants { get; set; }
}

public class Dependant{

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ResponsibleId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: RepoDB understand your schema and is projecting the model properties equality against the table columns from the database, therefore, such `[Ignore]` attribute is not needed anymore. PS: It was a part of the early code, but we had removed it as we improve the projection.

Comment: Tks @MichaelCamaraPendon I'll post your comment as answer!

Answer (score 1):

"RepoDB understand your schema and is projecting the model properties equality against the table columns from the database, therefore, such [Ignore] attribute is not needed anymore. PS: It was a part of the early code, but we had removed it as we improve the projection. - Michael Camara Pedon"

Comment: Why am I getting "invalid column name" then?